# How should you type a async thunk being passed as an argument?

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

Given the example below, I'm having a hard time figuring out what the `loadAction` argument should be typed as when passed to `connect`.

```
interface ApiResponse {
  data: string;
}

interface ApiErrorResponse {
  message: string;
}

const api = () =>
  new Promise<ApiResponse>((resolve) => {
    resolve({ data: "123" });
  });

const loadSomething = createAsyncThunk<
  string,
  void,
  { rejectValue: ApiErrorResponse }
>("something", async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
  try {
    const result = await api();
    return result.data;
  } catch (err) {
    if (!err.response) throw err;

    return rejectWithValue(err.data as ApiErrorResponse);
  }
});

const List = ({ data = "Something", loadAction }: ListProps) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await loadAction();
      if (result.type.endsWith("rejected")) alert("Failed");
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [loadAction]);

  return <div>#{data}</div>;
};

interface DispatchProps {
  loadAction: () => WhatTypeAmI?
}

interface OwnProps {
  data?: string;
}

type ListProps = DispatchProps & OwnProps;

const mapDispatch = {
  loadAction: loadSomething
};

const ListContainer = connect<void, DispatchProps, OwnProps, RootState>(
  null,
  mapDispatch
)(List);
```

I've tried:

`AsyncThunkAction<string, void, {}>` but then the compiler complains that `result` (inside my `useEffect` hook) doesn't have a type property.

`Promise<PayloadAction<object>>` but the compiler indicates that `loadSomething` is not compatible.

What's the proper type for `loadAction` that would satisfy all the requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually typing `connect` you can use the `ConnectedProps` helper to infer the types:

```js
const mapDispatch = {
  loadAction: loadSomething,
};

const connector = connect(null, mapDispatch);

type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;

interface ListProps extends PropsFromRedux {
  data?: string;
}

const List = ({ data = 'Something', loadAction }: ListProps) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await loadAction();
      if (result.type.endsWith('rejected')) alert('Failed');
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [loadAction]);

  return <div>#{data}</div>;
};

const ListContainer = connector(List);
```

Reference: [Inferring The Connected Props Automatically](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing#inferring-the-connected-props-automatically)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. While this does remove the need to manually type `DispatchProps` it doesn't fully answer the question. Imagine a scenario where `UsersList` is the connected component and it passes the `loadUsers` action down to a generic `List` component. Now I need to type the props the `List` component will receive and I still don't know that proper type for the action.